# Parse guid by Regular Expressions with slashes ('/') in C#

Tags: c#, regex, guid

Is there any way to parse regular expression like this

```
"/string1/string2/f63112f7-caae-38f4-9655-e23d6b530315"
```

and I want to get a string: 'f63112f7-caae-38f4-9655-e23d6b530315'

I tried to use the following code:

```
Match match2 = Regex.Match(input2, @"'/([^']*)");
```

or this one:

```
Match match1 = Regex.Match(input1, 
@"/((?:(?:\s*\{*\s*(?:0x[\dA-F]+)\}*\,?)+)|(?<![a-f\d])[a-f\d]{32}(?![a-f\d])|" +
@"(?:\{\(|)(?<![A-F\d])[A-F\d]{8}(?:\-[A-F\d]{4}){3}\-[A-F\d]{12}(?![A-F\d])(?:\}|\)|))");
```

but I unfortunately failed.

Is there any way to parse such string with returning guid?
Thanks in an advance.

Comment: Split and take last element would be easier, yes?

Comment: Um, find out the position of the last slash and grab everything that follows? Why are you even trying regular expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that without Regex, Split on `/` and then use `Guid.TryParse` the last element, or all the elements like:

```
string str = "/string1/string2/f63112f7-caae-38f4-9655-e23d6b530315";
Guid tempGuid;
foreach (var item in str.Split('/'))
{
    if (Guid.TryParse(item, out tempGuid))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
        break;
    }
}
```

If you are always expecting the `Guid` to at the end of string then instead of looping through all elements, just access the last element from the split array and use that in `Guid.TryParse`

```
if(Guid.TryParse(str.Split('/').LastOrDefault(), out tempGuid))
{
 //found Guid at the end of string
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below regex to match all the charcters which are next to the last `/` symbol,

```
(?<=\/)[^\/]*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yM0hT2/4)

C# code would be,

```
string str = @"/string1/string2/f63112f7-caae-38f4-9655-e23d6b530315";
string result = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=\/)[^\/]*$").Value;
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/pwU6mp)

Answer (score 2):

If you'd really like to use a regular expression, this would seem to work for your scenario:

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}");

Guid guid;
if (!match.Success || !Guid.TryParse(match.Value, out guid))
{
    guid = Guid.Empty;
}
```

As other answers have suggested, there are easier ways of doing it if your string is always in the expected format.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex, a simple `LastIndexOf` + `Guid.TryParse` works:

```
string guidString = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
Guid guid = Guid.TryParse(guidString, out guid) ? guid : Guid.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Split` and `Last`.
Guid has a ctor that inputs a string.

```
string str = "/string1/string2/f63112f7-caae-38f4-9655-e23d6b530315";
Guid g = new Guid(str.Split('/').Last());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
.*\/(.*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/tS9vT8/1)**

[image]